# how to speed up lemmatization using spacy.pipe on text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, nlp, spacy

How can I speed up lemmatization on text set using spacy pipe? Currently I'm using like this,

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
df['text'].apply(lambda x: len(nlp(x).ents)) # returns number of named entities
```

How can I use extract number of named entities using nlp.pipe with batch_size, threads etc.. and take advantage of multiprocesses?

```
spacy_nlp.pipe(df['text'], n_threads=6, batch_size=10)
```

Comment: You're saying "lemmatization" but you're talking about entity extraction. The inconsistency distracts from the question.

Comment: @EricMcLachlan I just wanted to show an example how I normally use spacy so someone can help me on how to actually use pipe with multi threads and batch size for lemmatization on a dataframe text column with high speed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [pipe](https://spacy.io/api/language#pipe) has an `n_threads` parameter but SpaCy 2.2.2 does provide a `n_process` parameters that indicates the "...Number of processors to use". So, you could distribute the load over your CPUs at the very least.

I'm honestly not sure how much you're going to be able to parallelize the processing of a single text. SpaCy is pretty damn fast already.

If you have a bunches of texts or extremely large texts that can be broken into sections, then you may benefit from distributing the load using something like the [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor), which distributes processing over a number of processes.

Unfortunately, because of Pythons notorious [Global Interpreter Lock](https://realpython.com/python-gil/), you're going to struggle to squeeze performance out via thread parallelization unless the processing is happening in a c library behind the scenes (like Numpy and TensorFlow).